# Java regular expression to organize document sections

Tags: java, regex

I have a file that contains multiple sections. The sections start with a number followed by some spaces and then a line of text, this line is followed by an empty line and then a paragraph.

Example:

> 1.2    Title of section
>     Sentence one.   Sentence two.  Sentence three.
>
> 1.3    Title of another section
>     Sentence one.  Sentence two.  Sentence three.

I need a regular expression to capture the text in each section. I want to do something like:

Find a number followed by a dot followed by another number followed by a space and then take all text that follows.

Currently I'm trying this `^\d+[.]\d+\s\(.)`

It isn't working properly now though. Any suggestions?

Comment: A better way of doing `[.]` is escaping the dot with a backslash `\.`

Comment: @Michael you were right :) I missed the complete question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex with lookahead and single line flag like this:

```
(\d\.\d)(.*?)(?=\d\.\d|$)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/ia22bL/1)**

Comment: Thank you so much!!